# help specifying a multilevel risk model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, risk

Hi and any help greatly appreciated specifying this model!

I have a binary outcome, measured at the person level (coronary event). There are 9 'risk event' predictors (also binary coded as occurred/not); things like 'family history, 'high-fat diet', 'low SES' etc. Some are correlated, some are not. ppl can experience a discrete number of these events coded as 1;s, the rest are coded as zeroes. I think of them as a subset of risk events from some hypothetical universe of risks that might have been experienced, so I am thinking of them as a random effect.

A person can have experienced some discrete number of the events, so I think that risks are nested within people. However I am having a hard time specifying the model as a multilevel model because the outcome is only measured once.

Can someone help me think through this model? I would like to specify a random effects model, but at a minimum I need to estimate the ICC for proportion of variance in the outcome explained by within person risk events vs between people variability.

Comment: So are you saying that your outcome is the total number of coronary events experienced by an individual? Relatedly, do you essentially have one row per data? In order to specify random effects at the level of the individual, you'll need, at a minimum, repeated measures of your dependent variable (i.e., multiple observations within a subject and not their total number of events).

Comment: Yes, the data are structured in person-row format, and all I have is whether they ever had a cardiac event. So it is becoming clear to me that a random effects model will not fit.

Comment: Then yes, I believe you are likely going to have to stick to a logistic regression for these data.

Comment: Hi - I hope this is the appropriate plae to ask this question - do comments count as answers? It's telling me to award the bounty to an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately from your data's description it does not sound like it is properly structured for a mixed effects model. You would need either a) repeated measures within individuals or b) multiple observations (i.e., different cases or individuals) collected from a larger grouping structure (e.g., cases nested within hospitals or within geographic regions).

Broadly speaking mixed effects models allow you to separate between- and within-nesting structures sources of variation. My recommendation, if you are looking at number of cardiac events as an outcome, and given your data's description, is that you consider a generalized linear model (perhaps a Poisson or negative binomial link function considering that you are working with count data).

Comment: A negative binomial model is efffectively a hierarchical model, with a Poisson likelihood in which the rate differs between patients according to a gamma distribution. The negative binomial formulation simply integrates out the explicit random subject effects.

Comment: I mention the negative binomial as an option as it has nice properties if there is overdispersion in the count data (the Poisson is essentially a special case of the negative binomial as you point out). A quasi-Poisson regression may also be appropriate in the presence of overdispersion [as described here](http://fisher.utstat.toronto.edu/reid/sta2201s/QUASI-POISSON.pdf). There is of course no one size fits all answer, and the link function is going to ultimately depend on what is appropriate for the data.